# Google maps hosted without internet connection

Tags: google-maps

Is it possible to host a deployment of google maps locally so that users, on a small local network, do not need an internet connection?  This is for a tradeshow project that will not have internet connectivity.
I'm hoping to get an answer from Google on this, the Dev site suggests that this is the place to ask.

Comment: The DEV site was wrong - [so] is for programming questions. Hosting Google Maps locally is off-topic.

Comment: I think generally speaking the dev site is probably referring to this being the place to ask programming questions about the API as mentioned above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I am aware it is not possible, the library functions often call external services for processing and the map tiles themselves cannot be downloaded. You could on the other hand use a local copy of [OpenStreetMap](http://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=5/51.500/-0.100) as a base layer and then either use a local copy of the maps API over the top (being careful which methods to call to avoid errors) or even using [OpenLayers](http://openlayers.org/) for your mapping functionality.

Hope this helps.